# Themes and Skins in .net

Tags: jquery, html, css, themes

I want to apply Themes and skins in my .net application.
Can you please suggest me sites from where I can download light weight themes. And theme must include demo for all controls.

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can google it and there are lot for global skin file in visual studio. you can download the skin from the following link

> http://www.telerik.com/support/skins.aspx

Comment: But I want a ready theme that includes demo for all controls of HTML.. so that I dont need to change them.